# Hats are back! Get them while they're hot!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, competitions, fun

The annual [Winterbash](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) is on again, so grab your hats while you can!

Expats's own [leaderboard is visible here](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/expatriates.stackexchange.com).